# Node Server not Visible in Web Browser on Port 4200 on localhost

Tags: node.js, linux, angular, development-environment

I am running a basic Angular server on my Pixelbook in Dev Mode.  I feel like I have done this a number of times on a normal Ubuntu development box, but something about this Chrome flavored development environment is vexing me.

I am able to start the server, which is basically a web server, and I am able to call it from a command line using wget.  However, when I pull this up using the Chrome browser, I get a connection refused error.

I think I altered the Chrome defaults to not be so restrictive (like not loading local content).

I am able to run the server using `ng serve`, and I have tried this specifying the host as 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, and localhost - but no luck.

I suspect this has something to do with either Chrome or the Pixelbook Linux environment.

Below are the basic troubleshooting that I have done so far.  Any other thoughts?

```
→ ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=4200
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2018-06-30T17:00:32.284Z
Hash: ebb64e6046efff317389AQ
Time: 8398ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 10.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.06 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

::Hit the server from command line - OK::

```
→ wget 0.0.0.0:4200
--2018-06-30 17:04:29--  http://0.0.0.0:4200/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:4200... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 581 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                     100%[=================================================>]     581  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-06-30 17:04:29 (37.5 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [581/581]
```

::Inspect the index.html to confirm it is a real HTML file::

```
○ → head index.html 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyAngularApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

::Open Chrome and navigate to 0.0.0.0:4200, localhost, etc.::

```
This site can't be reached
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

::Check the ip configuration::

```
→ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ea:0e:81:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth0@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:21:1b:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 100.115.92.198/28 brd 100.115.92.207 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe21:1bbe/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

::Check netstat and see what ports are being listened on::

```
→ netstat -noa|grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8889                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

::Validate IP Tables::

```
○ → sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:4200

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cookies and cache?  Chrome caches like crazy which can cause some false alarms.  If this is the issue I would suggest using incognito mode which will prevent the caching issues for the most part.

Comment: Good idea.  I went ahead and tried that.  I still get an connection refused error.

Answer (score 0):

Start server with:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

View it at: http://penguin.linux.test:4200/

The `penguin.linux.test` is essentially `localhost` on your Pixelbook.